# iphone presentModalViewController

Tags: iphone

I have an app, inside that an `UIViewController` is attached on the `UIWindow`.
on the view of `UIViewController`, i have added a button and a uiview_1 of size 100x80.
this uiview_1 contains another uiview_2 as subview of same size and this uiview_2 contains a `UIImageView` or a `UIlable` at runtime (both `UIImageView` and `UIlable` are `userinteraction` enabled)

now on the touch/click of `UIImageView`, i want to show a new view using `presentModalViewController`, the problem is the view is shown and using back button on the navigation bar i come to the previous/main screen.
here the problem come in picture, now i am unable to touch the button or the UIImageView.
both are not responding, but app is not crashed and nor frozen.

what is wrong in that?

Plz help in this...

-----  **EDIT**:

Approach First:

```
SWVController *swvController = [[SWVController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *viewNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:swvController];
UIViewController *pushController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
UIWindow *win = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
[win addSubview:pushController.view];
[pushController presentModalViewController:viewNavController animated:YES];
```

In the swvController i have back button that calls the dismissModelViewController on click >> result is the Main screen ctrls are not responding to touch – sandy 3 hours ago

Second approach:

```
SWVController *swvController = [[SWVController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *viewNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:swvController];
UIViewController *pushController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
[self addSubview:pushController.view];
[pushController presentModalViewController:viewNavController animated:YES];
```

In the swvController i have back button that calls the dismissModelViewController on click >> result is the swvController's back button on navbar is not responding – sandy 3 hours ago

3rd approach:

```
SWVController *swvController = [[SWVController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *viewNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:swvController];
SampleAppAppDelegate *appdel = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]; [appdel.viewController presentModalViewController:viewNavController animated:YES];
```

>> result is working fine, but the problem is i dont want to use SampleAppAppDelegate,i want to give my small Uiview (100x80) as a ctrl to other person , where my ctrl will not able to get the AppDelegate of thet app at run time. – sandy 3 hours ago

Answer (score 4):

Call this method when you want to present the modal view controller:

```
- (IBAction)showInfo {    
    FlipsideViewController *controller = [[FlipsideViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FlipsideView" bundle:nil];
    controller.delegate = self;

    controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];

    [controller release];
}
```

Add this method to your self:

```
- (void)flipsideViewControllerDidFinish:(FlipsideViewController *)controller {
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Use a toolbar or other button and connect it to this method in your modal view controller:

```
- (IBAction)done {
    [self.delegate flipsideViewControllerDidFinish:self];   
}
```

All code comes from Apple.

Answer (score 0):

How did you handled click/touch on `UIImageView`? TouchesBegan/Ended?

Try putting some logs (`NSLog`) and run your app in debug mode (put some breakpoints) to see if control reaches your action method...

Also, when you do `presentModalViewController`, you do not need to POP out with back button on navigation bar... you only need to `dismissModelViewController` to hide it.